# My Javascript ball moving code isn't working

Tags: javascript

I created a ball and some Javascript code that is supposed to make it move. But my code isn't working and I don't know why. Could someone please look over my code and help me out.

**Code**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var xPos = canvas.width/2;
var yPos = canvas.height-30;
var ballRadius = 10;
var leftPressed = false;
var rightPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;

function drawBall() {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(xPos, yPos, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 drawBall();
}
setInterval(draw, 10);

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);


function keyDownHandler(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 37) {
  leftPressed = true;
 }

 else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
  rightPressed = true;
 }

 else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
  upPressed == true;
 }

 else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
  downPressed = true;
 }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 37) {
  leftPressed = false;
 }

 else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
  rightPressed = false;
 }

 else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
  upPressed == false;
 }

 else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
  downPressed = false;
 }
}

if(leftPressed = true) {
 xPos -= 7;
} else if(rightPressed = true) {
 xPos += 7;
} else if(upPressed = true) {
 yPos -= 7;
} else if(downPressed = true) {
 yPos += 7;
}
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
  canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Breakout</title>
 
 <style>
  * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
  canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
 </style>

</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

<script src="gameJS.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only updating the boolean values during keypress. You're not updating the position dynamically. Your position update code runs first during load and that's it.

To move during keypress, you need to update the position during each keypress and you need to draw the ball.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var xPos = canvas.width/2;
var yPos = canvas.height-30;
var ballRadius = 10;
var leftPressed = false;
var rightPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;

function drawBall() {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(xPos, yPos, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 drawBall();
}
setInterval(draw, 10);

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
//document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);


function keyDownHandler(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 37) {
  xPos -= 7; 
        //draw the ball with new position
 }

 else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
  xPos += 7;
        //draw the ball with new position
 }

 else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
  yPos -= 7;
        //draw the ball with new position
 }

 else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
  yPos += 7;
        //draw the ball with new position
 }
}
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
  canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Breakout</title>
 
 <style>
  * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
  canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
 </style>

</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

<script src="gameJS.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: An error occurs: *Uncaught ReferenceError: keyUpHandler is not defined*.

Comment: Yes, because it's definition is removed. If you want it, put it back. If not, stop calling it from the listener. This is a very basic error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **assignment** operators (single equal signs) in your check for keypresses, rather than **comparator** operators (double equal signs). Essentially, you're saying that they should **equal** true, rather than checking if they **are** true:

```
if (leftPressed = true) {}
else if (rightPressed = true) {}
else if (upPressed = true) {}
else if (downPressed = true) {}
```

These should be written as:

```
if (leftPressed == true) {}
else if (rightPressed == true) {}
else if (upPressed == true) {}
else if (downPressed == true) {}
```

Having said that, you don't need to make use of these four variables at all, and can instead simply modify the positions directly on checking against the `keyCode` values:

```
if (e.keyCode == 37) {
  xPos -= 7;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code.

1. In your up/down key handlers you compare the value of upPressed instead of setting it.

e.g.

```
upPressed == true;
```

should be

```
upPressed = true;
```

2. In your if conditions at the end, you set the value instead of comparing.

e.g.

```
if(leftPressed = true)
```

should be

```
if(leftPressed)
```

3. I've moved the ball position code into the moveBall function and called that when the key handler is called so that the position is updated on key press.

This is the fixed version.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var xPos = canvas.width / 2;
var yPos = canvas.height - 30;
var ballRadius = 10;
var leftPressed = false;
var rightPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(xPos, yPos, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall();
}
setInterval(draw, 10);

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);


function keyDownHandler(e) {
  leftPressed = false;
  rightPressed = false;
  upPressed = false;
  downPressed = false;
  
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    upPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    downPressed = true;
  }
  moveBall();
}


function moveBall() {
  if (leftPressed) {
    xPos -= 7;
  } else if (rightPressed) {
    xPos += 7;
  } else if (upPressed) {
    yPos -= 7;
  } else if (downPressed) {
    yPos += 7;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use assignment operator `=` instead of comparison operator `==` for `upPressed` variable within `keyUpHandler` and `keyDownHandler` methods.
2. Don't set `leftPressed`, `rightPressed`, `upPressed` and `downPressed` values using by `=` operator within `if...else` conditions. Use comparison operator or logical values directly instead.
3. Update `xPos` and `yPos` values each time before `drawBall` method calling.

The working code below.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var xPos = canvas.width / 2;
var yPos = canvas.height - 30;
var ballRadius = 10;
var leftPressed = false;
var rightPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(xPos, yPos, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  SetPos();
  drawBall();
}

setInterval(draw, 10);

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    upPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    downPressed = true;
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    upPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    downPressed = false;
  }
}

function SetPos() {
  if (leftPressed) {
    xPos -= 7;
  } else if (rightPressed) {
    xPos += 7;
  } else if (upPressed) {
    yPos -= 7;
  } else if (downPressed) {
    yPos += 7;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `keyDownHandler` is called whenever a keydown event occurs, you'll want to move your position variables updating code to within that function, and you can remove the `keyDownHandler` as it doesn't do anything in this example:

```
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  //left
  if(e.keyCode === 37){
    xPos -= 7
  }
  //right
  else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    xPos += 7
  }
  //up
  else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
    yPos -= 7
  }
  //down
  else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
    yPos += 7
  }
}
```

In addition, you can make your code slightly more readable with a [switch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) statement rather than cascading **else if**

```
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  switch(e.keyCode){
    case 37: //left
      xPos -= 7
      break;
    case 39: //right
      xPos += 7
      break;
    case 38: //up
      yPos -= 7
      break;
    case 40: //down
      yPos += 7
      break;
  }
}
```

Note: as Obsidian Age correctly pointed out, you are using **assignment operators** and not **comparison operators** in your update code, so you might want to double check that in the future. In my example I used the triple equal `===` operator because it checks both type and value, which is recommended in JavaScript. See W3Schools reference for [JavaScript Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Just update your javascript as below will do the trick.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var xPos = canvas.width/2;
var yPos = canvas.height-30;
var ballRadius = 20;
var leftPressed = false;
var rightPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;

function drawBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(xPos, yPos, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if(leftPressed == true) {
    xPos -= 7;
    } 
    else if(rightPressed == true) {
    xPos += 7;
    } 
    else if(upPressed == true) {
    yPos -= 7;

    } 
    else if(downPressed == true) {
    yPos += 7;

    }


    drawBall();
}


function keyDownHandler(e) {

  var keyCode = e.keyCode;

    if(keyCode  == 37) {

        leftPressed = true;
    }

    else if(keyCode  == 39) {

        rightPressed = true;
    }

    else if(keyCode  == 38) {

        upPressed = true;
    }

    else if(keyCode == 40) {

        downPressed = true;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {

    var keyCode = e.keyCode;

    if(keyCode == 37) {

        leftPressed = false;
    }

    else if(keyCode == 39) {

        rightPressed = false;
    }

    else if(keyCode == 38) {

        upPressed = false;
    }

    else if(keyCode == 40) {

        downPressed = false;
    }
}
```